# Pymongo-text search-list of phrases

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I have a dictionary of the following structure:

```
keywords={topic_1:{category_1:['\"phrase_1\"','\"phrase_2\"'],
                   catgeory_2:[''\"phrase_1\"','\"phrase_2\"']},
          topic_2:{category_1:['\"phrase_1\"','\"phrase_2\"','\"phrase_3\"']}}
```

I have a bunch of documents in **mongodb** on which I want tag a [category,topic] tag as long as it matches any one of the phrases in the [topic][category].However I need to iterate phrase by phrase as follows(**Pymongo)**:

```
for topic in keywords:
  for category in keywords[topic]:
      for phrase in keywords[topic][category]:
            docs=db.collection.find({'$text':{'$search':keyword}},{'_id':1})
```

Instead of this I just want to scan the list of phrases and give me a list of documents that match **any one phrase** for every [topic][category] list.Is this possible in pymongo?...Is OR-ing of phrases possible?-If so how do I go about it?I tried concatenating the phrases as a single string but that dint work.My actual Mongo collection has a million documents and the dictionary would be very large as well-The performance is brought down if I iterate phrase by phrase

Comment: I am afraid you have no  alternatives here, it is not question of pymongo, rather it is a MongoDB limitation you can't do OR-ing of phrases.

Comment: @nickmilon Thanks-that's what I suspected!